# Scale field dependancies in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale

I have two map frames on my composer. One is a regional, large scale map, and the other is a local, small scale map. I would like the scale of the regional map to automatically update based on the scale of the local map.

For instance, my local map is map 0. I would like the expression in my scale field for my regional map (Map 1) to be 'Map 0 scale + 35000'. Is there a way to do this in the composer?

Answer (score 1):

In the Composition tab of the print composer, scroll down to Variables and

> add a variable called local_map_scale

Set the value of local_map_scale to the desired scale for the local map.

Now select "local_map_scale" as the scale for Map 0. Use the expression editor to set the scale for Map 1 as

> local_map_scale + 35000

In order to change the scale of the local map, you'll need to return to the Composition tab and change the value of the variable.

Comment: I can't figure out how to refer to the scale of one map in the scale expression editor for another map. Here's a slightly cumbersome workaround instead.